# AngularJS - wildcard in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ip-address, wildcard, ng-class

I am currently creating a webpage that's listing all the currently logged in users on our network.

The page is populated by a json file output by powershell and I am using AngularJS to bind the data from the json file to the webpage and I would like to apply a certain class to specific ranges of IP addresses to identify different locations etc.

For example 172.20.*.* is given the 'location1' class and 172.25.*.* is given 'location2' etc. I am trying to use ng-class to do this kind of like the following:

```
<div class="user" ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchFilter | orderBy: 'AssociatedUserFullNames'" ng-class="{location1: (user.ClientAddress == '172.20.*.*'), location2: (user.ClientAddress == '172.25.*.*')}">
```

Now I realise this is wrong and you can't use wildcards like this, but does anyone know how I can achieve this? I have tried regex as well but that doesn't seem to work either.

I am new to AngularJS and have tried reading through the documentation but can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about using indexOf?

```
location1: user.ClientAddress.indexOf("172.20") != -1 ....
```

But if you have way to many IP ranges then create a service which takes IP address and gives back css class names.